# How to Write to File in Subdirectory Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter

I can write to a file in current directory.
I cannot write to a file in a subdirectory.
I checked online but the posts and previous questions didn't really help.
I have the code below, it should write to File.txt which is inside Subfolder. However, instead of this, I get a new File called "SubFolder\File.txt" in my current directory.

Any help?

```
PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH+= 'SubFolder\File.txt'
fileInput = open(PATH, "w")
fileOutput = open("SubFolder\File.txt", "w")
```

I expect a file in a subfolder.
I get a file with the desired path as a file name. Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use double escape for file paths.

```
fileOutput = open("SubFolder\\File.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file for writing doesn't create any intervening subfolders that don't yet exist. You have to create them yourself first, using `os.mkdir()` (for one level) or `os.makedirs()` (for multiple levels).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "os.path.join" as it joins path with '//' or '\' as per required by OS instead of concatenating paths manually. So when file is opened using this PATH then it will go in dir/sub-dir structure instead of creating file named 'sub-dir/filename.exetension' within current directory. I have encountered same issue and this what worked for me.

PATH = os.getcwd()

PATH = os.path.join(PATH,'SubFolder','File.txt')

fileOutput = open(PATH, "w")